# When two new values are added to a SOAP webservice response, .Net suddenly treats empty arrays in the response as null, instead of empty. Why is this?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap, .net-4.0

### Background:

We have a SOAP web service in production, and a new instance of it in test. The new version adds two new values to the response, but changes nothing else. I used SOAP UI to inspect the actual responses, and here they are. Namespaces changed for privacy.

TEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <OutputParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://some.com/method/">
         <X_CONFIG_INFO>
            <SOVALID>1</SOVALID>
            <LINEVALID>0</LINEVALID>
            <BUILDVALID>1</BUILDVALID>
            <STATUS_MESSAGE>Invalid Sales Order Line Number for Sales Order: 10 and Line Number: 1</STATUS_MESSAGE>
            <SALESORDER>10</SALESORDER>
            <LINENUMBER>1</LINENUMBER>
            <LINEQUANTITY xsi:nil="true"/>
            <PARTNUMBER xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CUSTNUM xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CUSTNAME xsi:nil="true"/>
            <BOMSW/>
            <BUILDWITH/>
            <OPTIONS/>
            <ATTACHMENT/>
            <SMEN>N</SMEN>
         </X_CONFIG_INFO>
      </OutputParameters>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

PRODUCTION:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <OutputParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://some.com/method/">
         <X_CONFIG_INFO>
            <SOVALID>1</SOVALID>
            <LINEVALID>0</LINEVALID>
            <SALESORDER>10</SALESORDER>
            <LINENUMBER>1</LINENUMBER>
            <LINEQUANTITY xsi:nil="true"/>
            <PARTNUMBER xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CUSTNUM xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CUSTNAME xsi:nil="true"/>
            <BOMSW/>
            <BUILDWITH/>
            <OPTIONS/>
            <ATTACHMENT/>
            <SMEN>N</SMEN>
         </X_CONFIG_INFO>
      </OutputParameters>company
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The four properties: BOMSW, BUILDWITH, OPTIONS, ATTACHMENT are arrays. When there is no data, they come across as empty elements.

I used Beyond Compare to compare the two responses, and they are identical except that the Test version has two new elements in the response: BUILDVALID and STATUS_MESSAGE.

I have a .Net app that has a Service Reference (WCF) to this web service. I have two versions of that app. I'll call them "old" and "new". The old code is currently deployed on thousands of machines in our company. Not every machine needs the new version with the new values, but they might occasionally call the new method with the old code. The new client code will only be deployed to a few machines at first, but the web service obviously is all or nothing.

I would not have thought that adding a couple of values to the output XML would make a difference to the old code. If the service proxy code generated by Visual Studio uses XPath to read the values, then it should totally ignore the new values.

### Problem:

In the old code, the .Net service proxy translates the empty elements in the Production response into **empty** arrays.

When the *same code* receives the Test response above, it translates the empty elements into **null** arrays.

This crashes the old code because it doesn't check for nulls. This is obviously a bad practice, but it is what it is. The code is already in production. The new code has been altered to check for nulls, but due to logistic issues, it can't be deployed everywhere at once.

Why would adding two new values to the XML response cause WCF to turn the empty arrays into null arrays?

I should add that the webservice is hosted in Oracle. It's based purely of of a pl-sql package that get auto generated into a web service. There's no chance to do anything fancy on the server side.

Comment: Are you running the same version of .NET and Visual Studio as you were when the proxy was first created? It would be interesting to look at a proxy you generate today, pointing to the Production service (without the new fields).

Comment: I'm running literally the same executable. Against production it's fine. Against Test the arrays are null.

Comment: Same executable, but which .NET version is installed?

Comment: Ok. I get what you're saying, but it doesn't help answer the question. The build version has increased since the original executable was made. But I'm testing with the old executable.

Comment: No, seriously, is it the same version of the .NET Framework installed on both machines, or are they different versions?

Comment: I'm only using one machine, my development box. One executable, one machine, two servers with two different responses. Two different behaviors based on the response.

Comment: what happens when you build the old code without the fields?  It works just fine?  But when you add the new fields it suddenly fails?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you wrote the code to add those two properties. I presume DataContracts so I will suggest an answer along those lines.

The is answer is one word **Versioning**. Thats it.

Check the following articles and references for implementation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352586/WCF-Backward-Compatibility-and-Versioning-Strate

Hope it helps.

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon.  I would recommend including the relevant parts from the links in your post (as links can die). Also this does not answer the question at hand, while it is great advice going forward.

Comment: I added a note to my post. We can't do anything fancy on the server. I'm really looking for the answer of *why* this happens. It makes no sense to me.